# How to have three models linked in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I currently have a User model, Chasing model and a Comments model.

The User `has_many :chasings` and the Chasing model `belongs_to :user` and `has_many :comments`

I created a migration to add a reference to :chasings for :user, so I could call Chasing.user:

```
class AddUsersToChasings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :chasings, :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

So I can now successfully assign chasings to users, however I'm wanting to find out the best way of assigning comments in chasings to users using a similar select list as below (this is the code for selecting users for chasings):

```
    <%= f.select :user_id, options_for_select(User.all.map {|c| [c.name, c.id]}, @chasing.user_id), { :include_blank => "Please select user"}, {:class => "form-control"} %>
```

Anyone got any ideas on how I'd create the relationship between comments and users, if the comments already belong_to the chasing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able reference comments through chasings as such:

```
class User
  has_many :chasings
  has_many :comments, through: :chasings
end
```

That way you have access to `User.first.comments`, the same way you had for `User.first.chasings`

Comment: Will I need to create a migration for this to reference :commments to :user?

Comment: no, that's already inferred from the current :chasings association.

Comment: Ah, might be kind of a nooby question, but would you know how I'd modify my above form code so I could assign the users to the comments? When I use the above code I get `undefined method `user_id' for #<Comment:0x94e7380>`

Comment: That's because the user_id is defined on the chasings model. One question though is: if chasings is assigned to user already, why do you still have to assign comment?

Comment: I have a list of chasings, which have users assigned to them, but I also want to use these users for comments on individual chasings, seperate to the main chasing

Answer (score 0):

The comments still needed to be assigned to chasings, but each comment needed to have a user assigned to it, pulled through from the user model. To do this I added `has_one :user` to my Comment model, and `has_many :comments` to my User model. I also ran the following migration to create the relationship between the two:

```
class AddUsersToComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :comments, :user, index: true, foreign_key: true      
  end
end
```